# How to delete all rows between two number values in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, gaps-and-islands

I have a table with two columns, `id` and `typ`:

```
DECLARE @tb1 AS TABLE (id INT, typ INT)
INSERT INTO @tb1
(
    id,
    typ
)
VALUES
(1,1),(2,3),(3,2),(4,3),(5,1),(6,2),(7,3),(8,3),(9,1)
,(10,3),(11,3),(12,3),(13,2),(14,3),(15,1)
```

When looking at the rows ordered by `id`, I want to delete all rows that are between a row with `typ = 1` and the next row with `typ = 2` that follows.

I want this result:

```
id          typ
----------- -----------
1           1
3           2
4           3
5           1
6           2
7           3
8           3
9           1
13          2
14          3
15          1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a classic gaps and islands problem type question.
I recommend that you read through this excellent **[article](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/the-sql-of-gaps-and-islands-in-sequences/)** on gaps and islands.

You can use a query like below 
<kbd>**[See working demo](http://rextester.com/JYELO70441)**</kbd>

```
;
with BoundarySuspects as 
(
    select 
        a.*, 
        seqNumber=row_number() over( order by id asc)
    from @tb1 a
    where a.typ=1 or a.typ=2 
 ),
 GapMap as
 (
     select 
        GapFrom= a.id,
        GapTill= b.id
    from BoundarySuspects a
         join
         BoundarySuspects b
        on a.typ=1 and b.typ=2 and b.seqNumber=a.seqNumber+1 
 )
    select 
        t.* 
     from @tb1 t 
         left join 
     GapMap g
         on t.id >GapFrom and t.id <GapTill
     where GapFrom is NULL
```

Comment: @mhsankar Glad to be of help! Hope you give back to SO community by adding more valuable questions and answers and staying active here.

Answer (score 3):

Try this out

```
DECLARE @idtype1 int, @idtype2 int

DECLARE type_cursor CURSOR FOR   
SELECT a.ID as ID_TYPE_1, b.ID as ID_TYPE_2  
FROM (SELECT ID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY_ID) AS RN
    FROM TABLE WHERE TYPE = 1) a
INNER JOIN (SELECT ID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY_ID) AS RN
        FROM TABLE WHERE TYPE = 2) b
    ON a.RN = b.RN

OPEN type_cursor  

FETCH NEXT FROM type_cursor   
INTO @idtype1, @idtype2  

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  
    DELETE FROM TABLE WHERE ID BETWEEN @idtype1 AND @idtype2

END
```

Comment: @Alfin-e-r with `cursor` it takes very time . i want faster solution please

Comment: So far I could only think that cursor is the best way to do it, because its execution is row basis that require fetching rows to get the parameter between which id to which id, which then to be applied into delete condition

Comment: @AlfinE.R. There's a term called RBAR often used around in SQL community[https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/rbar-row-by-agonizing-row/].  Central idea of SQL operations should be to avoid loops and get work done using set based approach.

Answer (score 3):

First you have to indentify the boundaries of what you want to remove:

```
SELECT
    T1.id as StartId,
    (SELECT MIN(T2.id) from @tb1 T2 WHERE T1.id < T2.id and T2.typ = 2) as EndId
from @tb1 T1
WHERE T1.typ = 1
```

Result:

```
StartId  EndId
1        3
5        6
9        13
15       NULL
```

You can then use this query in a CTE (Common Table Expression) to do the actual removal:

```
DECLARE @tb1 AS TABLE (id INT, typ int)
INSERT INTO @tb1 (id, typ)
       VALUES (1,1),(2,3),(3,2),(4,3),(5,1),(6,2),(7,3),(8,3),(9,1),(10,3),(11,3),(12,3),(13,2),(14,3),(15,1)

;WITH ranges AS (
    SELECT
        T1.id as StartId,
        (SELECT MIN(T2.id) from @tb1 T2 WHERE T1.id < T2.id and T2.typ = 2) as EndId
    FROM @tb1 T1
    WHERE T1.typ = 1
)
DELETE T3
FROM @tb1 T3
INNER JOIN ranges ON T3.id > ranges.StartId and T3.id < ranges.EndId

SELECT * FROM @tb1
```

Answer (score 1):

this query should work

```
delete from @tb1 where id < 13 and id > 9
```

delete where typ is between 10 and 12 [borders included]

Comment: i have type 1, 2 and 3 - how can set where with type 13 and 10?

Comment: so please improve your question, from your output the thing i can understand is you removed ID between 9 and 13

Comment: I want to delete all row are between type 1 and 2 . do you understand my question?

Comment: 'betwenness' doesn exists in SQL rows, each row can be in a 'random' position due to execution query plan. you have to find a condition across  values

Comment: rows between type 1,2 - for example delete rows with id 2 - because rows before that have type 1 and after that have type 2.